# increment the value of id in windows application(net) through database

Tags: visual-studio

if i click a button the last value in id  should be incremented and displayed in the textbox in windows application(.net).

eg..

in database there are 10 records... in the column id from 1 to 10... if i click the button 
 the value should be increment and 11 should be shown in my textbox in windows application..
please send as soon as possibe

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify that the ID column in your DB is an "identity" column. Then, when you insert a new record into the table, SQL will automatically assign the new record with the previous highest value in that column incremented appropriately (you can have SQL increment by 1 or more if you wish).

David Hayden wrote up a nice little article on this very subject[link text](http://www.davidhayden.com/blog/dave/archive/2006/02/16/2803.aspx):
http://www.davidhayden.com/blog/dave/archive/2006/02/16/2803.aspx